# Is there any way to list latest Nexus Artifacts in Jenkins?

Tags: groovy, nexus, jenkins-groovy, nexus3, jsonslurper

I am using Acive Choice Reactive Parameter plugin to list down Nexus Artifacts. This is the groovy script which I'm currently using.

```
import groovy.json.*

def targetUrl = "https://nexus.xxxx.lk/service/rest/v1/search?repository=snapshots&format=maven2&group=com.org.pro&name=pro-service"
def jsonSlupper = new JsonSlurper().parse(URI.create(targetUrl).toURL())
def list = jsonSlupper["items"]["version"].collect().sort().reverse()
```

I want to display only latest artifact in the list. Does anyone know, how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

we can use metadata API, you can use snapshots repo or release repo or public for both, just limit the last 5 versions.

[Jenkins snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqENK.png)

```
def host="https://msnexus.xxx.com"
def groupId="com.xxx.cd".replaceAll("\\.", "/")
def artifactId="common-log"
def nexus_url="${host}/repository/public/${groupId}/${artifactId}/maven-metadata.xml"
def response=nexus_url.toURL().text
def metadata = new XmlParser().parseText(response)

metadata.versioning.versions.version.takeRight(5).collect({it.text()}).reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

Nexus does support sorting (... and also limits the amount of returned results to 50 by default, see `continuationToken`).

So to only get the latest versions, adjust your search url to include `sort=version&direction=desc`, (this does support semver):

```
def targetUrl = "https://nexus.xxxx.lk/service/rest/v1/search?sort=version&direction=desc&repository=snapshots&format=maven2&group=com.org.pro&name=pro-service"
def jsonSlupper = new JsonSlurper().parse(URI.create(targetUrl).toURL())
def list = jsonSlupper["items"]["version"].collect().take(5)
```